# iOS - Traceroute command

Tags: ios, networking, traceroute

I am looking for a way to use `traceroute` command in iOS application. This can be done since iNet Tools app can do that.
I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212038/can-you-do-a-ping-or-traceroute-command-on-iphone) questions in SA.
But other than that I wasn't able to find a hint how to accomplish that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm amazed that this question has not received enough attention. Have you found any way to do this yourself?